# Can my computer handle the NVIDIA GTX 750 TI?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply

I have an old office pc, and I want to update it with a somewhat old graphics card but that at least allows me to play some games, these are my PC specs:
Motherboard: PEGATRON CORPORATION 2AC2
CPU: i3 2120
RAM: 8GB
PSU: 250W (I'll update this, i know the gtx 750 ti requires a 400w psu, my biggest concern is the motherboard)
1366x768 Monitor VGA
SSD 700GB
I ask because I tried to put another graphics card on this pc but it didn't work (when I turned on the pc it only showed me a BIOS screen and nothing happened), so, I hope you can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Do the intended grahics card and the monitor have compatible ports, e.g. do they both have VGA, or both have DVI, or both have HDMI?

Comment: I believe the graphics card has VGA, and the monitor has it too

Answer (score 0):

The official answer is no.  http://www.pc-specs.com/mobo/Pegatron_Corporation/Pegatron_2AC2/2965/Compatible_GPUs

However, the specs show 3 x PCIe x1 v2.0 and 1 x PCIe x16 v2.0 so you should be able to slot it.  With a ti, you might lose some performance.